# How do I install Scala in Jupyter IPython Notebook?

Tags: scala, jupyter

Here's a few links that I went to and did exactly what they said. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

https://github.com/alexarchambault/jupyter-scala
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPython-kernels-for-other-languages
https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree
http://jcrudy.github.io/blog/html/2013/12/08/introduction_to_iscala.html

None of this is working. It may be some way that my node is configured. I just don't know. Please help.

Comment: a) What OS are you on: Linux/ MacOS, Win10? b) "None of this is working" What are your symptoms? You can start Jupyter, but Scala is not listed as a type? or what?

Answer (score 22):

I tried the following with Jupyterhub notebook and it works seamlessly:

```
# Step 1: Install spylon kernel
pip install spylon-kernel

# Step 2: create a kernel spec
python -m spylon_kernel install

# Step 3: start jupyter notebook 
jupyter notebook
```

PS: to list all installed kernels, you can run the following command:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

Comment: Today this answer works, the higher rated answer of Isaac is outdated.

Comment: According to their GitHub and also my initial exploration, Spylon  seems to be rusty if you aims for scala+python use on Jupyter (I install it for casual Scala + Spark + Jupyter on windows so I don't need to access my Linux VM or cloud for Scala+Spark).

Comment: It says `Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter'` but my Jupyter is located in a venv at `/home/username/.local/bin/jupyter`. Is there a way to install it in the right place? (venv)

Comment: This was the perfect answer.Thanks

Answer (score 17):

You can use the information given [here](https://libraries.io/github/jupyter-scala/jupyter-scala).

> Ensure you have IPython 3 installed. ipython --version should return a
>   value >= 3.0. If it's not the case, a quick way of setting it up
>   consists in installing the Anaconda Python distribution, and then
>   running
>
> `$ pip install --upgrade "ipython[all]"`
>
> ipython --version should then return a value >= 3.0.
>
> Download the Jupyter Scala binaries for Scala 2.10 ([txz](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/alexarchambault/jupyter/jupyter-scala-cli_2.10.5/0.2.0-SNAPSHOT/jupyter-scala_2.10.5-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.tar.xz) or [zip](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/alexarchambault/jupyter/jupyter-scala-cli_2.10.5/0.2.0-SNAPSHOT/jupyter-scala_2.10.5-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.zip)) or
>   Scala 2.11 ([txz](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/alexarchambault/jupyter/jupyter-scala-cli_2.11.6/0.2.0-SNAPSHOT/jupyter-scala_2.11.6-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.tar.xz) or [zip](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/alexarchambault/jupyter/jupyter-scala-cli_2.11.6/0.2.0-SNAPSHOT/jupyter-scala_2.11.6-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.zip)), and unpack them in a safe place. Then run
>   once the jupyter-scala program (or jupyter-scala.bat on Windows) it
>   contains. That will set-up the Jupyter Scala kernel for the current
>   user.
>
> Check that Jupyter/IPython knows about Jupyter Scala by running
>
> `$ jupyter kernelspec list`
>
> This should print, among others, a line like
>
> scala211
>
> (or scala210 dependending on the Scala version you chose).
>
> Then run either IPython console with
>
> `$ ipython console --kernel scala211`
>
> and start using the Jupyter Scala kernel straightaway, or run Jupyter
>   Notebook with
>
> `$ jupyter notebook`
>
> and create Scala 2.11 notebooks by choosing Scala 2.11 in the dropdown
>   in the upper right of the Jupyter Notebook start page.

**Note:**  Since IPython has now been replaced by Jupyter, we replaced `ipython` in the above commands with `jupyter`.

Comment: didn't work fpr me, maybe the answer is to old...I'm using ipython-7.7.0 on macOS.

Comment: follow the same step and it works on Windows. Reference path to Jupyter may cause a problem though and be careful.

Answer (score 6):

#### I've just run:

- `conda create --name base2 --clone base` to create an env just like *base*.
- `conda activate base2` to move to the *new* env.
- `conda install -c conda-forge spylon-kernel`.
- `python -m spylon_kernel install --user`. create a kernel spec for Jupyter notebook
- `jupyter-notebook`

...and works just fine.

I'm using:

- Anaconda 4.7.12
- Jupyter-notebook 6.0.1
- Ubuntu 18.04
- ipykernel 5.1.3
- ipython 7.9.0
- ipython_genutils 0.2.0
- jupyter_client 5.3.4
- jupyter_core 4.6.0
- traitlets 4.3.3

from `def suma(a: Int) = a + 3`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I can't add a comment to Heapify's answer, but his solution worked for JupyterLab on Windows without problems.

I cut and pasted his code into an Anaconda Powershell prompt

```
pip install spylon-kernel
python -m spylon_kernel install
jupyter notebook
```

And refreshed my anacopnda launcher and the spylon project option was available.

Comment: getting `
    from .scala_kernel import SpylonKernel
  File "/home/icmuser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spylon_kernel/scala_kernel.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .init_spark_magic import InitSparkMagic
  File "/home/icmuser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spylon_kernel/init_spark_magic.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .scala_interpreter import init_spark
  File "/home/icmuser/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spylon_kernel/scala_interpreter.py", line 84
    nonlocal spark_jvm_proc`

Answer (score 2):

The answer for Linux can be found [here](http://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/Jupyter.html).

> Install Scala. Add these lines to ~/.bashrc
>
> export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/share/scala export
>   PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin:$PATH 
>   Follow these instructions from the
>   GitHub site:
>
> [Download and unpack pre-packaged binaries Scala 2.11.](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/sh/jove/jove-scala-cli_2.11/0.1.1-1-SNAPSHOT/jove-scala-cli_2.11-0.1.1-1-SNAPSHOT.tar.gz) Unpack each
>   downloaded archive(s), and, from a console, go to the bin
>   sub-directory of the directory it contains. Then run the following to
>   set-up the corresponding Scala kernel:
>
> ./jove-scala --kernel-spec

Comment: Useful to point out this is only for Linux. The OP did not specify which OS.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure spark is installed in local along with `SPARK_HOME` is added or exported in `.profile/environment` file.

If not, you might get stuck with the following message:

```
"Intitializing Scala interpreter ..."
```

without any result.

Answer (score 2):

For mac, I needed only to 3 commands to add Scala and run it with Spark (I had it already installed)  on my Jupyter notebook

> `pip install spylon-kernel`
>
> `python -m spylon_kernel install`
>
> `ipython notebook`

Once you run them on your terminal, you'll have spylon-kernel in your notebook, which can be used as your a Scala notebook.

Answer (score 0):

`spylon-kernel` hasn't seen an update in years. These days its much better to use [almond](https://almond.sh/).