# Downloading scala into Anaconda

Tags: scala, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to download Scala as a package into anaconda as apparently you can use Scala within jupyter notebooks as a kernel. However, I have followed every explanation of what to do in order to get Scala downloaded into anaconda to no avail. I have switched the anaconda channel to bioconda to try conda installing scala, I have tried to create a new environment from the yaml file with the scala package information, I have tried pip installing scala, and I have tried downloading the sbt (which doesn't have much info on integrating it into anaconda). Supposedly anaconda is capable of working with scala as well as the website mentions it's scala compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

pip install will not work 
for conda install you can follow

```
conda install -c anaconda-cluster scala
```

Similar question where you can find more detail on installing kernel directly [How do I install Scala in Jupyter IPython Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563545/how-do-i-install-scala-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook)

Comment: I noticed that the package is only available for Linux and OsX, so, if you're running Windows you will have to install Scala manually.

Comment: Its mid-2022 and that is still the case. No windows.